# ANDROID ConstraintLayout - how to make a view stetch to the entire width and height of remainder of screen?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

hey can someone paste this code and tell me why i am not able to stretch the pink textview to fill the remainder of the empty screen. 
Here is my code using constraintLayout primarily:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            fontPath="fonts/Medium-Extd.otf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/check_out"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nsv_checkout_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:background="#dadbdd"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cvOne"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:elevation="4dp">


            <ViewFlipper
                android:id="@+id/switcher"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:measureAllChildren="false">


                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/clPaymentSuccessful"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="26dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/bag_icon_heart"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="tvStatus"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
                        fontPath="fonts/Medium-Extd.otf"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv"
                        tools:text="Payment Successful"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvAmount"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvStatus"
                        tools:text="$3,800 USD"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvOrderNum"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"

                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvAmount"
                        tools:text="your order is 7900434343"/>

                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            </ViewFlipper>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/switcher_cta"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/watermelon"
            android:measureAllChildren="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_close_cta"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cvOne">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/clcta"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvShowStaffCta"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:text="Show this screen to Store Staff to complete your purchase"/>

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </ViewFlipper>


        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_close_cta"
            fontPath="fonts/Medium-Extd.otf"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="41dp"
            android:background="@color/action_blue"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/close"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

there is a viewflipper called switcher_cta i just want that to take up the remainder grey area of the screen. how can i stetch it ?

Comment: why ? because of this `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` set it to `0dp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have correctly set constraints to top and bottom, but in order for them to work the View's height must be set to 0dp.

Also avoid setting match parent in ConstraintLayout , since your view is aligned left and right to parent, setting width to 0dp will fill up the space.

```
<ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/switcher_cta"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/watermelon"
            android:measureAllChildren="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_close_cta"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cvOne">
```